# Powershell XML node behaviour

Tags: xml, powershell

I got an XML, if he has no data for a certain timestamp he makes no entry, but to convert this to a Excel sheet I need to replace the non-existing value with an 0 inside an array, if it really exists i take that measure and put it inside my array.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -le $applicationArray.Length - 1; $i++) {
    $node = $xdoc3.dashboardreport.data.chartdashlet[$i]
    $node.name   
    for ($j = 0; $j -le $aantaldagenInDeMaand - 1; $j++) {  
        try {
            if ($node.measures.measure.measure.measurement[$j].timestamp -ne $allDates[$j]) {
                $LastmesOG += "0"
            }
            else{
                    $LastmesOG += $node.measures.measure.measure.measurement[$j].sum
            }
        }
        catch {
            $LastmesOG += "0"
        }   
        $index++
        Write-Host "name: " $node.name " i: " $i " measure: " $LastmesOG[$j] " j: " $j
    }
}
```

As you'll see in my output the name i get from the chartdashlet-node is correct, but all the measures keep coming back from the first chartdashlet-node. 
How does this happen?

Example output:

```
APP1
name:  APP1 i:  0  measure:  840.0  j:  0
name:  APP1 i:  0  measure:  718.0  j:  1
name:  APP1 i:  0  measure:  106.0  j:  2
name:  APP1 i:  0  measure:  6.0  j:  3
APP2 
name:  APP2 i:  1  measure:  840.0  j:  0
name:  APP2 i:  1  measure:  718.0  j:  1
name:  APP2 i:  1  measure:  106.0  j:  2
name:  APP2 i:  1  measure:  6.0  j:  3
APP3 
name:  APP3 i:  2  measure:  840.0  j:  0
name:  APP3 i:  2  measure:  718.0  j:  1
name:  APP3 i:  2  measure:  106.0  j:  2
name:  APP3 i:  2  measure:  6.0  j:  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay after 2 hours of frustrastion and just posting this, I found it. The $LastmesOG values were added, but i always called the first values of it because of $LastMesOG[$j], instead its now $Lastmesog[$lastmesog.length-1]